# puppeteer scroll until a specific button or div

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

How can I (and I don't know if it possible) scroll until an element?
For example I want to scroll until

```
await page.$x("//span[contains(., 'Post picture')]");
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const [span] = await page.$x("//span[contains(., 'Post picture')]");
await page.evaluate((element) => { element.scrollIntoView(); }, span);
```

Comment: yes! it works, I'd like to put the scroll in a timer in order to have a real scroll, do you have a snippet?

Comment: No, sorry. Try to ask in a different question)